# Half glossy half matt pot

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image: Plant Pot Reference]

So, I was wondering how you would be able to make a single cycles material which is half glossy (one color) and half matt (the other color).

The object in question is half blue gloss with no bump mapping and half white no gloss with ceramic bump mapping but I'm not quite sure how to get it to work - I figured out to use gradient and color ramp but I'm stuck from there.

Thanks!

What my cycles are so far:
[image: Cycles So Far]

Comment: you could use an Image Texture as a mask, plugged into the factor of a Mix shader in order to separate the 2 textures. The blue texture itself would need at least one Mix shader, as you have a brighter and a darker blue, maybe a Noise Texture could be the mask, it depends the level of resemblance you want

Answer (score 1):

You can define a mask to control where different textures etc are to be applied. A mask is usually a black and white image were black equals zero and white equals one. Connecting the mask into a mix shader node lets you choose between two different shaders, connected to a mix RGB node will choose between two colours.

Using a gradient texture to generate a mask.

[image: a procedural mask]

With your example you can also connect the mask to the roughness input of your principled BSDF node.

[image: mask with principled bsdf]

For more control you can use texture painting to draw a mask on your model, then connect an image texture node in place of the above colour ramp.